# How to get the row index of a Grid Element (Vaadin Flow)

Tags: vaadin-flow

I am using Vaadin 14 (currently rc7).

Getting the row index of a Grid with a `ListDataProvider` is simple. I use the code below.

```
final Collection<T> c = ((ListDataProvider)grid.getDataProvider()).getItems();
final List<T> list;
if (c instanceof List) {
    list = (List)c;
} else {
    list = new ArrayList(c);
}
return list.indexOf(item);
```

However, how to get this in the generic use case, not assuming a `ListDataProvider`?

**Use Case**

Make a specific row visible in the Grid based on some app logic, so "scroll to a row".

Comment: Hi. Maybe if you enlighten me about the use case here... Do you actually need the index for the DOM element or it's something related to it's data?

Comment: @M.Trojahn Good point, added the underlying use case

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is addComponentColumn, which you could add an extra div and set a different id per row to it and try to navigate to that. But it's gonna be really hacky.

Comment: Is this question still open?